# Flutter - Hot to android overlay using native kotlin Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I make CallApp using Flutter.

When I get a call, the Kotlin Broadcast receiver checks it and then, i want to look android overlay.
(like swift callkit)

i looked flutter official document. but it was written about only call kotlin func in flutter.

help me...

Comment: Can you add the kotlin code?

Comment: I put the 3 code files below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.